# How to enable HMR for a library?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to figure out how to enable HMR and/or live-reload for a project that creates library bundles. These bundles are dynamically loaded by a custom Javascript framework that utilizes an express server.  So I'm trying to use webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware in my express app to make this happen.

Besides the server-side changes, I've made updates to my webpack config to specify webpack-hot-middleware/client as an entry point and included the HotModuleReplacementPlugin.  When I access the application via the browser I can see a message in the console log that indicates that HMR is active so I think my basic configuration is correct.  However, when the bundle is loaded initially it does not appear to have the interface that the library exports but instead it contains an interface specific to HMR eg. methods like setOptionsAndConnect, subscribe, etc.  Since the interface is not the one exported from the library, the code fails to work correctly.

My browser console.log shows:

[HMR] connected

so I think that the basic plumbing is correct.

It's worth noting that if I remove the hot middleware then changes to the source code for the library bundle correctly cause the bundle to be recompiled, but I need to manually refresh the browser in order to see the updates.  I'm hoping that I can use HMR to at least force an automatic browser refresh (if not an in-place update) after the bundle is re-compiled.

My webpack.config looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports {
    mode:'development',
    output: {
        library: "foo",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/dist"),
        publicPath: '/assets/js/dist'
    },
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "js/foo.js"),
        webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=200000"
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')
    }
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();
    ]
}
```

My express server contains:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

const wpconfig = require('path/to/webpack/config');
const webpackCompiler = webpack(wpconfig);

const wpmw = webpackDevMiddleware(webpackCompiler, {
    publicPath: wpconfig.output.publicPath
})

app.use(wpmw)

const wphmw = webpackHotMiddleware(webpackCompiler);
app.use(wphmw);
```

My expectation is that, after a change to the library code, the bundle will be automatically regenerated and the browser refreshed to display the updates.

Any suggestions for a configuration that will make this work would be most appreciated.